# How to send a chat message to microsoft teams user from an external system upon event?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I need help with Microsoft teams integration. I have an system from which I want to send chat message to a particular user in MS teams upon an event in my system. How do I go about implementing this. The teams graph api documentation is not looking clear to me. Like it has body but no head and tail. I'm confused on where to start for this. I understand I need to use Graph API's create/send chat api to send messages but it says I need to configure a delegate user for this? How do I send messages on behalf of a external system? Can I can use Teams Java sdk based application? Or I need to create a bot? But I think it's for one-2-one conversation is it? I only want to send a one way message from external system to user. Someone with experience in this pls help me on a good approach for this.

All I want is to send chat message from external system to a user in teams.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You have two major tasks: a) Microsoft Graph authorization and b) Teams send chat message. Edit your question and show the code you have written and the problem that you have. If you have not written any code, start by sending a Teams chat message using your identity. The rest will fall into place once you understand the basics. Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Graph API in this scenario if you want it on behalf of External system. The API is only available when you are having delegated permission.

Other option would be to create a Notification only bot. In this case please keep in mind that the bot needs to be installed in Teams of user you want to send notification. You can use this graph API to install bot in user's Teams- [Install app for User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Once it is installed you need to have user's [`Conversation.Id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.conversationaccount.id?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Schema_ConversationAccount_Id) and [`ServiceUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.activity.serviceurl?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Schema_Activity_ServiceUrl) (*maybe store it in database for all users*). When you are done with everything you can send [Proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive).